# Copying several filtered columns' worth of non blank cells to second sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table that I need to autofilter itself according to criteria in column "AS", then copy multiple discrete columns' worth of resulting non-blank cells to specific cells in the next sheet.

What is the most efficient way of doing this? I'm aware that I may have to copy/paste specialvalues instead of direct reference

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.  But, imagine Column A is filled with names of fruits and Column B is filled with numbers.  The following code filters Column A with the criteria "Apples" and copies the corresponding numbers to a new worksheet.  This might start you off on the right track.

```
Sub selectApples()

' Find last row in column A
Dim LastRow As Integer
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Select data in column A and filter
Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Select
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Apples"

'Find new last row
Dim newLastRow As Integer
newLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Copy and paste special into new worksheet
Range("B2:B" & newLastRow).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: is there any way to reference more than 2 cells in Range()?

Comment: actually, to clarify, Range("H2:H" & newLastRow, "I2:I" & newLastRow, "V2:W" & newLastRow, "AD2:AD" & newLastRow).Select throws an error "range of object_global failed"